# When executing an SQL query using session.execute(sql_to_string()) I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_string'

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, dbeaver

When I run the below:

```
# 'session' points to a databse    

t = tuple(a_list_of_ids)
query = "select val from sval where id IN {}".format(t)

ids_to_delete = session.execute(sql_to_string(session, query))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/some_path/find_and_delete_ICE_contracts_non_tradeable_first_alive.py", line 34, in find_ice_contracts_on_dte
    is_tradeable_values_of_ids_to_soft_delete = session.execute(sql_to_string(session, query))
  File "some_path/util/sql_translation.py", line 621, in sql_to_string
    return stmt.as_string(psycopg2_connection)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_string'
```

Any ideas how to format the above so that it works?

I also tried `session.execute` without the `sql_to_string`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Convert the list to ids string
a_list_of_ids = [1, 2, 3]  # Example list of IDs
id_string = ', '.join(str(id) for id in a_list_of_ids)

# Make Query Here (notice the id_string is wrapped in brackets
query = "SELECT val FROM sval WHERE id IN ({})".format(id_string)

# Then Execute
result = session.execute(query)
```

Comment: Thanks you Sir, do you import `text`? Or where would I get it from?

Comment: @jikf no need for text, you can use my now updated code